# Satellite Broadband - Safe?

Tags: security

I am looking at Tooway Satellite Broadband (20mbps). It beams down to their ground station in Italy. Is this safe to use with Tor?

Answer (score 1):

Tor is designed to prevent the Internet access provider — or an eavesdropper monitoring the access — from learning which sites are accessed. So using Tor can help defeating surveillance on a satellite connection. The latency of using Tor is likely to be important due the the high latency of satellite links.